# Theory of computation

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

I am trying to look answer for this question of toc please help me find the answer.
The question is :
Construct epsilon NFA(Non deterministic finite automata) for regular expression (0+1)*1(0+1)

Comment: Start with the easy parts: (0+1). Make one (0+1)*. Can you fill the gap?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13606/755